# How to prove that equivalent spinless $p$ wave superconductor can be emerged from $s$ wave superconductor + topological insulator heterojunction?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, majorana-fermions

In L. Fu and Kane's paper they that spinless px+ipy wave superconductor can emerge from s wave superconductor + topological insulator  heterojunction,But my result is not the same as their paper.Could you figure out my mistake in derivation.

**The hamiltonian of 2D TI:**
$$H_{0}=\psi^{\dagger}\left[ v\sigma_{x} p_{x} + v\sigma_{y} p_{y} -u  \right] \psi$$
Then we add the s wave superconducting term to $H_{0}$,and write it in a matrix form:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \begin{split}
 H=
 \left[ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  -u&vp_{x}+ivp_{y}&0&\triangle \\
  vp_{x}-ivp_{y}&-u&-\triangle&0 \\
  0&-\triangle&u&-vp_{x}-ivp_{y} \\
  \triangle&0&-vp_{x}+ivp_{y}&u
 \end{array}
 \right] 
 \end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
$\triangle$ is superconducting term,u stand for chemical potential.
$\Psi=[\psi_{\uparrow},\psi_{\downarrow},\psi^{\dagger}_{\downarrow},-\psi^{\dagger}_{\uparrow}]$

In order to obtain the property of quasipartical,we diagonalize the $H_{0}$
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
H_{0}=
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cc}
-u&vp_{x}+ivp_{y} \\
vp_{x}-ivp_{y}&-u
\end{array}
\right] 
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
eigenvalue:$E=kv\pm u$
Basis transformation:
$$c_{\uparrow,k}=\psi_{\uparrow,k}+e^{i\theta}\psi_{\downarrow,k}$$
$$c_{\downarrow,k}=\psi_{\uparrow,k}-e^{i\theta}\psi_{\downarrow,k}$$
Then expansion $\psi$ by the new base function.
$$\psi_{\uparrow,k}=c_{\uparrow,k}+c_{\downarrow,k}$$
$$\psi_{\downarrow,k}=0.5*e^{-i\theta}[c_{\uparrow,k}-c_{\downarrow,k}]$$
Then pose time reversal symmetry onto the above two equation.
$$\psi_{\downarrow,-k}=c_{\downarrow,k}-c_{\uparrow,-k}$$
$$-\psi_{\uparrow,-k}=0.5*e^{i\theta}[c_{\downarrow,-k}+c_{\uparrow,-k}]$$
Combine the two pairing together:
$$\triangle \psi_{\uparrow,k} \psi_{\downarrow,-k}=\triangle [c_{\uparrow,k}+c_{\downarrow,k}]*[c_{\downarrow,k}-c_{\uparrow,-k}]$$
This is not the same as in L. Fu and Kane's paper,what's wrong with my derivation?

[image]

Reference:Superconducting proximity effect and Majorana fermions at the surface of a
topological insulator

> [Blockquote](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1692)

```
enter preformatted text here
```